# htaccess Rewriterule if url contains a specific word, keep the rest of URL

Tags: url-rewriting

Facebook recently added a tracking script/parameter: &fbclid=....
So when people click on a link from a Facebook page which refers to my website (portfolio), my website can't find the right page.

An example:
This is the url facebook creates: http://stanbroeksteeg.nl/portfolio?video=296818340&fbclid=IwAR1OuXwzLVBQDFSgeNzCVgJ7lkCNhWeHZwhOe2vs9SmZzCYFMcBDJ6N-lX8

My website quickly changes it to: 
http://stanbroeksteeg.nl/portfolio?video=296818340&fbclid

This results in the page not being found. So what i want to do is the following:
If the url contains &fbclid remove this part and KEEP the rest of the URL. So if i take the example URL is needs to be like this:
http://stanbroeksteeg.nl/portfolio?video=296818340

I've come up with this these Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} “fbclid=” [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?fbclid=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

But both rules do not resolve the issue.
Can somebody help me with this?

This is my current .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive on

   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my problem

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?fbclid=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Hope it can help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

@Bram's solution worked in my Wordpress. Here is the .htaccess code before and after.

Before:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

After:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?fbclid=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```