# Facebook's fbclid parameter is blocking my adsense ads on my website. How can I eliminate this?

Tags: url-parameters

When I share an article from my website to Facebook, Facebook adds a fbclid parameter code which affects the Adsense ads from appearing when someone clicks on the link. When they are redirected to the article, no ads appear. It's like Facebook's fbclid code is blocking my Adsense ads from appearing. It's costing me thousands of dollars a month. Is there a way around this?

I've researched everything and can't find an answer.

I want my facebook followers to be able to click on the link and go to my website and see the ads, but facebook's fbclid is blocking that.

Comment: Hi there, I'm experiencing the same too and haven't been able to find an answer. Just to compare, what kind of webserver are you running? I'm running LiteSpeed with the LSCache plugin. Is your site WordPress based?

Comment: Here an answer worked for me:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984196/htaccess-rewriterule-if-url-contains-a-specific-word-keep-the-rest-of-url][1]