# Rewrite rule(s) to suppress more than one tracking parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, privacy

[One Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984196/htaccess-rewriterule-if-url-contains-a-specific-word-keep-the-rest-of-url#52987333) tells a way to remove fbclid from a request.  I need to do that because it causes Wordpress to throw 404.  But I also want to remove other tracking parameters.

Do all rewrites require two lines, condition followed be replacement?  What I would like to do would be something like this one-line perl regexp:

```
's:[\?\&](fbclid|gclid|utm\w)+::gi';
```

and there could be more than one on a line, possibly with legitimate parameters between them.  Also, my regexp is not exactly correct, because if there are other parameters, the question mark and/or ampersand must not be deleted.

Do I have to do a separate condition and replacement for each of the possible unwanted parameter names?

Answer (score 0):

With some experimenting, I found this to eliminate the 404:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)(&?(fbclid|gclid|utm_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1
```

but it leaves the unwanted parameters in the address bar.  Perhaps that's OK—a 301 or 302 might tell whoever is tracking what they wanted to know.  (I don't know)